# Give row names to table

Tags: r, matrix, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file which somewhat looks like this:

[image]

I need to cluster "NoOffaces" and count how many datasets has 1 face, 2 face and so on.

Here is what I did in **R**:

```
data<-read.csv('test.csv')
a<-table(data$NoOffaces)
a  #for printing a
```

And here is the output:

```
 0   1   2   3   4    5   6   7   8   9  10  14  15  19 
448 375 104  33  16   7   4   2   2   3   1   3   1   1
```

But, I want to give name to the first two rows so that it looks somewhat like this

```
 Faces :0   1   2    3   4    5   6   7   8   9  10  14  15  19 
 Count :448 375 104  33  16   7   4   2   2   3   1   3   1   1
```

I am not able to name the rows, also how to access the each value in the column?

Comment: Ok @akrun. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @akrun, there is only one variable so the "table" is very likely a vector...

Comment: Yes, it looks like vector ! What should I do now? @CathG

Comment: I mean it is like mapping ! 0->448, 1->375 and so on. I would like  to name it as count.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Gotcha. [tag:import-from-csv], R's [tag:read.csv], Python's tags and others need dealing with, too.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a matrix based on the table and assign row names to it.

```
# an example vector
x <- c(1:5, 1:3, 4:6)

a <- table(x)

mat <- rbind(as.numeric(names(a)), a)
rownames(mat) <- c("Faces", "Count")
mat
#       1 2 3 4 5 6
# Faces 1 2 3 4 5 6
# Count 2 2 2 2 2 1
```

Comment: I wonder why is there extra row, i.e the first row of your final mat?

Comment: @JayPatel These are the column names.

Comment: One more issue, how to access only the first row and only the second row?

Comment: @JayPatel Use `mat[1, ]` for the first and `mat[2, ]` for the second row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which is the best resource to leaen R programming? Any book or videos?

Comment: mat[1, ] and mat[2, ] prints the same output.

Comment: @JayPatel The output is different for me. You may want to have a look at the official R introduction: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html.

Comment: @JayPatel In your matrix `mat2` the rows contain identical values (except the row names).

Comment: Yes, it gives same results because, my faces and count rows are same. I don't know how are the same!

Comment: @JayPatel Did you forget the `names` function? Use `mat2 <- rbind(as.numeric(names(a)), a)`.

Comment: ohhoo!! :( My bad. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose something like that would work :

```
t(data.frame(Faces=names(a),Counts=as.vector(a)))
```

Also you can keep `a` as it is, `names(a)` gives you the faces and `a` the corresponding counts...

Comment: @JayPatel, it transposes the data.frame, else Faces and Counts would be columns.