# Make a named table from list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a column with Id of a product and a list of data frames with characteristics about them:

#### bundle dataframe

```
 bundle
1  284993459
2 1048768805
3  511310430
4 1034630958
5 1235581326
```

#### d2 list

```
[[1]]
    id value
1   35   0.2
2 1462   0.2
3 1109   0.2
4  220   0.2
5  211   0.1

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
    id name value
1  394        0.5
2 1462        0.5

[[4]]
    id name value
1  926        0.3
2 1462        0.3
3  381        0.3
4  930        0.2

[[5]]
    id name value
1  926        0.5
2 1462        0.5
```

I need to create columns with all characteristics ID  and their values for each product.

```
bundle =  data.frame(bundle =  c(284993459,1048768805,511310430,1034630958,1235581326))
d2<- list(data.frame(id = c(35,1462,1109,220,211), value = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.1)), 
                    data.frame(id = NULL, value = NULL), 
                    data.frame(id = c(394,1462), value = c(0.5,0.5)),
                    data.frame(id = c(926,1462,381,930), value = c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.2)),
                    data.frame(id = c(926,1462), value = c(0.5,0.5))) 

         bundle    35 1462 1109 220 211 394 1462
    1  284993459   0.2  0.2  0.2 0.2 0.1   0    0
    2 1048768805     0    0    0   0   0   0    0
    3  511310430     0    0    0   0   0 0.5  0.5
```

Can't figure out how to do this. Had an idea to unlist this data frame list, but no good came of it, since a have more than 8000 prodict IDs:

```
for (i in seq(d2))
  assign(paste0("df", i), d2[[i]])
```

If we take a different approach than I have to to join transposed  characteristics data frames so the values are filled row by row.

Comment: Can you provide us a reproducible example so we can test ? I mean, give use the code to obtain the lsit of dataframes.

Comment: Is the length of `bundle` == the length of the list?

Comment: @LAP Yep, it's the same. 8660 bundles and 8660 dataframes with characteristics

Comment: @OrhanYazar Sure, will edit in a minute

Comment: This is just multiple joins. The result strictly isn't an R table object, it's still a dataframe. If it was an R table, you'd need [Give row names to table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774426/give-row-names-to-table-in-r)

Comment: you have 6 bundles but 5 data.frames, and an output with 3 bundles, can you clarify ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper 6 bundles 6 dataframes, 2nd one is empty dataframe.

Comment: That's not what I see, I see first a column with 6 values then a list of 5, but in the next chunk it's 5 and 5 so I suppose this is a mistake.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I see, the print and the example data do not match. But I think you got the solution right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. First we add a bundle column to all `data.frames` and stitch them together using `purr::map2_dfr` , then use `tidyr::spread` to format as wide.

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- map2_dfr(bundle$bundle,d2,~mutate(.y,bundle=.x)) %>%
  spread(id,value,)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
#       bundle  35 211 220 381 394 926 930 1109 1462
# 1  284993459 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.2  0.2
# 2  511310430 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.5
# 3 1034630958 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.2  0.0  0.3
# 4 1235581326 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0  0.5
```

Comment: Gives me an error: _Error in UseMethod("mutate_"): no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"_

Comment: with your real data or with the sample data you provided ?

Comment: With the real data, although the real data has exactly the same look, but more rows

Comment: You could use `class`, `summary`, `str` etc to diagnose the differences between your sample data and real data, if it works with your sample data there's not much more I can do. If you can build a minimal reproducible example from your real data that makes my solution fail I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/nikitapronin/furry-parakeet
Here is the original data.

Comment: We really need a reproducible example posted in the question Nikita, these questions and answers are supposed to benefit to the next users. One suggestion: try to sample 10 row numbers and extract a sample from `bundle` and `d2` for those, do it with different seeds if necessary until you can reproduce the crash, then post it in your original question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the bundle to each data.frame within the list, then pivot it using `reshape2::dcast` or `data.table::dcast` before updating NAs to 0

```
ans <- data.table::dcast(
        do.call(rbind, Map(function(nm, DF) within(DF, bundle <- nm), bundle$bundle, d2)),
    bundle ~ id)
ans[is.na(ans)] <- 0
ans

#      bundle  35 211 220 381 394 926 930 1109 1462
#1  284993459 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.2  0.2
#2  511310430 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.5
#3 1034630958 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.2  0.0  0.3
#4 1235581326 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0  0.5
```

edit: adding more explanations after OP's comment

1) `function(nm, DF) within(DF, bundle <- nm)` takes the input data.frame DF and adds a new column called `bundle` with values equal to `nm`.

2) `Map` applies a function to the corresponding elements of given vectors. (see `?Map`) That means that `Map` applies the above function using each of the `bundle` values and add them to each data.frame in `d2`

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, but i have an issue:_ Error in UseMethod("within") :   no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "NULL"_

Comment: You can add if(!is.null(DF)) in front of within

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- rbindlist(
  lapply(lapply(d2, function(x) if(nrow(x)==0) data.frame(id=NA, value=NA) else x),  #in case there is no dataframe row in a list assign a blank dataframe
         function(y) y %>% spread(id, value)), #convert all dataframes in wide format
  fill = T) %>%                                #rbind all dataframe in a single dataframe
  select(-`<NA>`) %>%
  cbind.data.frame(bundle = bundle$bundle)
```

**Output is:**

```
    35 211 220 1109 1462 394 381 926 930     bundle
1: 0.2 0.1 0.2  0.2  0.2  NA  NA  NA  NA  284993459
2:  NA  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 1048768805
3:  NA  NA  NA   NA  0.5 0.5  NA  NA  NA  511310430
4:  NA  NA  NA   NA  0.3  NA 0.3 0.3 0.2 1034630958
5:  NA  NA  NA   NA  0.5  NA  NA 0.5  NA 1235581326
```

**Sample data:**

```
bundle <-  data.frame(bundle =  c(284993459,1048768805,511310430,1034630958,1235581326))
d2 <- list(data.frame(id = c(35,1462,1109,220,211), value = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.1)), 
           data.frame(id = NULL, value = NULL), 
           data.frame(id = c(394,1462), value = c(0.5,0.5)),
           data.frame(id = c(926,1462,381,930), value = c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.2)),
           data.frame(id = c(926,1462), value = c(0.5,0.5)))
```

Comment: Gives me an error: _Error in if (nrow(x) == 0) data.frame(id = NA, value = NA) else x :   argument is of length zero_

Comment: Can you share `dput(d2)`? It runs perfectly fine on the sample data mentioned in your post (or the one which I have used in my answer). In the meantime you can try replacing `if(nrow(x)==0)` code in my answer with `if(nrow(x)==0 | is.null(x))`.

Comment: github.com/nikitapronin/furry-parakeet Here is the original data.

Comment: This seems to be a raw data. I would suggest to upload the processed data which you have posted in your sample using `dput(head(d2)`. You may want to see his [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches which differ only in the sequence of operations:

1. Reshape all dataframes in the list individually from long to wide format and `rbind()` matching columns.
2. `rbind()` all dataframes in long form and reshape to wide format afterwards.

Both approaches require to include `bundle` somehow.

For the sake of completeness, here are different implementations of the second approach using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
d2 %>% 
  # bind row-wise into large data.table, create id column
  rbindlist(idcol = "bid") %>% 
  # right join to append bundle column
  setDT(bundle)[, bid := .I][., on = "bid"] %>%
  # reshape from long to wide format
  dcast(., bundle ~ id, fill = 0)
```

> ```
>        bundle  35 211 220 381 394 926 930 1109 1462
> 1:  284993459 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.2  0.2
> 2:  511310430 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.5
> 3: 1034630958 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.2  0.0  0.3
> 4: 1235581326 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0  0.5
> ```

Here, piping is used just to visualize the sequence of function calls. With `data.table`'s chaining the statement becomes more concise:

```
library(data.table) # library(magrittr) not required
setDT(bundle)[, bid := .I][
  rbindlist(d2, id = "bid"), on = "bid"][, dcast(.SD, bundle ~ id, fill = 0)]
```

or

```
library(data.table) # library(magrittr) not required
dcast(setDT(bundle)[, bid := .I][
  rbindlist(d2, id = "bid"), on = "bid"], bundle ~ id, fill = 0)
```

---

Another variant is to rename the list elements before calling `rbindlist()` which will take the names for creating the `idcol`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
d2 %>% 
  # rename list elements
  setNames(bundle$bundle) %>%
  # bind row-wise into large data.table, create id column from element names
  rbindlist(idcol = "bundle") %>% 
  # convert bundle from character to factor to maintain original order
  .[, bundle := forcats::fct_inorder(bundle)] %>%
  # reshape from long to wide format
  dcast(., bundle ~ id, fill = 0)
```

> ```
>        bundle  35 211 220 381 394 926 930 1109 1462
> 1:  284993459 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.2  0.2
> 2:  511310430 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.5
> 3: 1034630958 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.2  0.0  0.3
> 4: 1235581326 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0  0.5
> ```

---

Note that the variants presented so far have skipped the empty dataframe which belongs to `bundle` 1048768805 (likewise the answers by [Moody_Mudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50465826/3817004) and [chinsoon12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50465211/3817004)).

In order to keep the empty dataframe in the final result, the order of the join has to be changed so that all rows of `bundle` will be kept:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(
  rbindlist(d2, id = "bid")[setDT(bundle)[, bid := .I], on = "bid"], 
  bundle ~ id, fill = 0
  )[, "NA" := NULL][]
```

> ```
>        bundle  35 211 220 381 394 926 930 1109 1462
> 1:  284993459 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.2  0.2
> 2:  511310430 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.5
> 3: 1034630958 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.2  0.0  0.3
> 4: 1048768805 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.0
> 5: 1235581326 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0  0.5
> ```

Or, if the exact order of `bundle` is to be maintained:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(
  rbindlist(d2, id = "bid")[setDT(bundle)[, bid := .I], on = "bid"], 
  bid + bundle ~ id, fill = 0
)[, c("bid", "NA") := NULL][]
```

> ```
>        bundle  35 211 220 381 394 926 930 1109 1462
> 1:  284993459 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.2  0.2
> 2: 1048768805 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.0
> 3:  511310430 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.5
> 4: 1034630958 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.2  0.0  0.3
> 5: 1235581326 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0  0.5
> ```

Comment: I have an error: _Error in rbindlist(., idcol = "bundle") : Item 3 has 3 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 2 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE._

Comment: Apparently, not all of the dataframes in the list have the same structure (same number, order, and type of columns). Suggested solutions: (1) Either you can fix the input data or (2) a special treatment for the deviating dataframes has to be included in the code.